# How are you supposed to register a macro twig in drupal 8

Tags: php, twig, drupal-8

I have a macro twig located at /my-module/templates/menu_macros.html.twig where in it looks like.

```
    {# /my-module/templates/menu-macros.twig #}
    {# Handles making of the anchor #}
    {% macro anchor(linkUrl, value) %}
    <a href="{{ linkUrl }}">
        {{ value }}
    </a>
    {% endmacro %}
```

and then in my template directory my-module/templates/sport-subnav.menu.html.twig

```
{%  block subnav %}
{% import "menu-macros.html.twig" as _macro %}
{% endblock %}
```

This throws error

```
Twig_Error_Loader: Template "menu-macros.html.twig" is not defined (Drupal\Core\Template\Loader\ThemeRegistryLoader: Unable to find template "menu-macros.html.twig" in the Drupal theme registry.) in "modules/custom/my-module/templates/sport-subnav.html.twig" at line 11. in Twig_Loader_Chain->getCacheKey() (line 129 of /tmp/local/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Chain.php).
```

I just want it to import my macro's!

Comment: Read the error: files called `menu_macros.html.twig` your importing `menu-macros.html.twig`

Comment: sorry this wasn't copy and paste.  typo here only.  Either way I figured it out.    
 the '@' is used as a pointer to your repo.  `{% import "@my-module/menu-macros.html.twig" as _macro %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{% import "@my-module/menu-macros.html.twig" as _macro %}`

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is too dumb, but how was I supposed to figure it out? There's nothing about this in documentation.

Comment: what was your question?